# How to restart my guitar studies from scratch?

Tags: theory, guitar, practice, learning, fingerstyle-guitar

I have being playing the guitar for quiet a while now(12+ years but more dormant years within this). I am able to deduce guitar tabs of a given song on my own(mostly with some minor errors). I have made a completely independent fingerstyle version of a song(and tried for other songs, but have mostly remained unsuccessful, and I made peace with guitar tabs). I know how to vary the strumming pattern within a given song. I know Rumba Flamenco variations upto some extent. But above all of this, I innovate and try to insert my own style in whatever I play.

Now, I did learn from a guitar teacher when I had started out, but in all truth, this teacher didn't teach me music theory or so. Most of what I am capable of performing on my guitar is by practice based on learning from youtube videos, etc.

Now, I want to rigorously begin from the beginning, starting from music theory concepts, etc.

My goal is to become more independent in case of fingerstyle guitar. Learning as much as possible.

Comment: The easiest approach will be to get a good teacher.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The one best solution, having tried others, is to get back with a teacher. There are many questions/answers here regarding establishing an appropriate teacher. One who works with you successfully may not work so well for others, and vice versa, so you need to make a list of what skills, activities, pressures are appropriate, along with costs, availability, and, if you like, prowess and qualifications. Past records of students' achievements may be a good yardstick, but please read the other q/as.

Failing that, and there may be many good reasons for not using a teacher, there are workshops and open mic sessions, where you could go and rub shoulders with other guitarists - sometimes free, sometimes at a cost. You could also have a look at some of the exam board material available for guitar - RGT and Rockschool come to mind, not necessarily to take the exams (although that in itself isn't a bad move), but to immerse yourself more thoroughly in guitarring, in several different genres.

P.S. do not allow yourself to become reliant on tab, you will live to regret it!

Comment: From my heart, I want to properly progress in fingerstyle, but I have failed to make any significant progress in it. So, it felt maybe I need to revisit the basics, besides I don't know much about music theory(but I do want to), just practical usage of stuff. Yes, lead chords seem dry by themselves without having an environment of beats(one way to interject fingerstyle...).

Comment: i had this experience with bass - I went right back to "three blind mice" to fix my timing and some bad habits. A teacher is a good suggestion though you can get quite far with self-discipline also.